# JavaScript dropdown menu does not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, onchange

I'm using an on change for a drop down menu to display information once a choice is chosen from the `dropdown`. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but I have been hoodwinked into having to use ie8 and this on change does not seem to fire. Any help would be much appreciated. Its a mix of php and html the lower part is js which outputs info when chosen.

```
echo "<p><h2> To View a Route: </h2><br> Pick a routes name from the list and all its information can be viewed below the selection box.</p>";
    echo "<p><FORM METHOD=\"post\" ACTION=\"controller.php\">";

    echo "<select class=\"toggle-data\" name='selectallrouteinfo'>";
    echo "<option value=\"\">Choose a Route </option>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list1); $i++) { //going through each element of array and outputting route
        if (is_string($list1)) {
            echo "<option value=\"\" data-toggle = \"$id1\" >$list1</option>";
        } else {
            $space = " ";
            $id = $list4[$i];
            $id1 = "#" . $list4[$i];


            echo "<option data-toggle = \"$id1\" value=\"$id\">" . $list1[$i] . $space . $id . "</option>";

            $idHolder[$i] = $id; //array for holding ids so that it passing the correct id to my loops below
        }
    }

    echo "</select></form></p>";
    for ($k = 0; $k < sizeof($idHolder); $k++) { //my outer loop is going through the ids, fitting correct id to the div and dbm obj
        echo "<div id=\"$idHolder[$k]\" style=\"display: none;\">
";
        $allRouteInfo = $DBM1->getAllRouteData($idHolder[$k]);
        for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($allRouteInfo); $j++) { // my inner loop is going through each element of array and outpting all route info
            if (is_string($allRouteInfo)) {

                echo $allRouteInfo; //if theres no info, there is no array, it has returned a string
            } else {

                echo $allRouteInfo[$j]; //if there is arry, happy days
            }
        }

        echo "</div>";




    //below is a js/jquery script for outputting my choice in the select of route info
    echo " <script>$('.toggle-data').on('change', function() { //jquery for printing my valuable info on change
                    var toggle = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-toggle'),
                       toggle_class = 'unique_classname'; 
                     $('.'+toggle_class+', '+toggle).toggle().removeClass(toggle_class);
                            $(toggle).addClass(toggle_class);
                        }); </script>";


    echo " </div>";
```

Comment: Post (and debug) the code that *actually gets sent to the browser*, not...whatever that is. (PHP?)

Comment: IE8 has a built-in debugger. What do you see when you use it?

Comment: Posting badly aligned HTML and JavaScript written in PHP strings is no good.

Comment: Im not sure what exactly to debug, i have actually posted what is displayed when choice is made. Apologies for absent code